# PowerBI - Creating Network International Days as a Measure

Tags: powerbi

I have a Requirement where in I have 2 Tables, Table 1 - DateTable and Table 2 - MyTable.

I am trying to calculate the Network International days similar to what we do in Excel.

> Note : My 2 Tables are not connected as they don't have a key
>
> DateTable has the Holidays in the column Holiday.
>
> MyTable has my date in the column SubmittedDate.

How would you solve this and create a measure to calculate the networking international days?

Schema as Requested:

```
MyTable 
Name RequestID SubmittedDate ExpectedResult
XABI 209874    25/7/2017     3

DateTable
Holidays Day   Reason
28/7/2017 Friday blabla
27/7/2017 Thursday blaalala
```

ExpectedResult is what I want to calculate - It is 3 because there are only 3 working days which is 25/7,26/7,31/7(today).

28/7 and 27/7 is a company holiday and 29/7, 30/7 are weekend holidays.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: We don't know what you do in excel. You should post your schema, sample data, and expected results.

Comment: Why can't you create a relationship between `SubmittedDate` and the `DateTable`?

Comment: DateTable only has some dates in it and if I create a relationship on what basis its going to match? It will throw a lot of null values.

Comment: @user5226582 I have added the Schema to the question. Kindly see if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`holidays` table (`DateTable` in your example):

```
date
2017-01-02
```

`calendar` table (introduced):

```
date
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
2017-01-05
2017-01-06
2017-01-07
...
```

`data` table (`MyTable` in your example):

```
date
2017-01-01
2017-01-03
```

add a calculated column to the `calendar` table:

```
isworkingday = 
var isweekend = if(WEEKDAY(calendar[date])>5, 1, 0)
var isholiday = if(CONTAINS(holidays, holidays[date], calendar[date]), 1, 0)
return if(AND(isweekend=0, isholiday=0), 1, 0)
```

add a calculated column to the `data` table:

```
workingDaysPassed = 
var curr = data[date]
return calculate(sum(calendar[isworkingday]),
    and(calendar[date]>=curr,
        calendar[date]<=today()),
    all(data))
```

`workingDaysPassed` should be your `ExpectedResult`, as long as you populated the `calendar` table:

```
date,       isworkingday, workingDaysPassed
2017-01-01, 1,            4
2017-01-02, 0,            3
2017-01-03, 1,            3
2017-01-04, 1,            2
2017-01-05, 1,            1
2017-01-06, 0,            0
2017-01-07, 0,            0
```